# Proof that $1/\sqrt{x}$ is itself its sine and cosine transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

As far as I understand, I have to calculate integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos \omega x \operatorname{d}\!x$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin \omega x \operatorname{d}\!x$$

Am I right? If yes, could you please help me to integrate those? And if no, could you please explain me.

EDIT: Knowledge of basic principles and definitions only is supposed to be used.

Comment: The first one I am not sure, is this integral convergent? It creates issues at 0. The second one can be perhaps be done with Laplace transform. You do need the gamma function to deal with that squareroot.

Comment: This is the task from the textbook and all previous tasks were relevant to current knowledge, which doesn't particularly include Laplace transform etc., so I hope, there is a simpler way (Anyway, it's a _definite_ integral, so - easier way may still exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^{-1/2} e^{i \omega x}$$

Substitute $x=u^2$, $dx=2 u du$ and get

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} du \, e^{i \omega u^2}$$

The integral is convergent, and may be proven so using Cauchy's theorem.  Consider

$$\oint_C dz \, e^{i \omega z^2}$$

where $C$ is a wedge of angle $\pi/4$ in the first quadrant and radius $R$.  This integral over the closed contour is zero, and at the same time is

$$\int_0^R dx \, e^{i \omega x^2} + i R \int_0^{\pi/4} d\phi \, e^{i \phi} e^{-\omega R^2 \sin{2 \phi}} e^{i \omega R^2 \cos{2 \phi}} + e^{i \pi/4} \int_R^0 dt \, e^{-\omega t^2} = 0$$

The second integral, because $\sin{2 \phi} \ge 4 \phi/\pi$, has a magnitude bounded by $\pi/(4 \omega R)$, which vanishes as $R \to \infty$.  Therefore

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{i \omega x^2} = e^{i \pi/4} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-\omega t^2} = e^{i \pi/4} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\omega}}$$

Therefore

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^{-1/2} e^{i \omega x} = (1+i)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{\omega}}$$

The Fourier cosine and sine transforms follow from taking the real and imaginary parts of the above.  Note the dependence on $\omega^{-1/2}$ times some scale factor.

Comment: What a nice solution, thank you very much. Exactly within boundaries of my current knowledge but enough tricky for me to miss the bus. Thank you!

Comment: @cdshines: you're welcome.  Please remember to accept an answer that is useful to you.

Comment: That's a clever solution indeed. I am jst wondering why the differential is immediately behind the integral sign and not behind the integrated expression? It looks kind a odd...

Comment: You could also integrate $f(z) = z^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{i \omega z}$ around a wedge of angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$ that is indented at the origin.

Comment: @imranfat: it is common in physics and especially optics which is my background.  You are hardly the first to ask about this (even today!).

Comment: @RandomVariable: could you please elaborate on that? I think, I understood the basic idea of Ron's answer, but I'd like to see how does this work once more.

Comment: @RandomVariable: indeed I could, but I think what I posted is simpler, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @RonGordon: I think, I'm still a little confused by that long middle-part integral. Is that an integral by the arc bounding the wedge?

Comment: @cdshines: yes.  The integral over $\phi$ is a parametrization of the arc.  Note that it only goes to $\phi = \pi/4$, so that defines the bounds of the integral.

Comment: @RonGordon, that's new to me. I am not into optics, but did physics as a part of my math undergrad, not in the USA though, and we indeed had to put differentials at the end. How about integration in multiple vars, where the order of dx,dy,dx matters for the integration, can you also freely put them in front of the expression? Kinda curious now....

Comment: Hi Ron, I think your answer may be off by a factor of $2$.

Answer (score 4):

First, use the change of variables $ y=\omega \,x $
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos \omega x\, dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega} }\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\cos y\,dy\,.$$

Then, use the Mellin transform method  (using the tables)

$$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x) dx .$$

Now, the [Mellin transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) of $\cos(y)$ is $$ \Gamma  \left( s \right) \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \,s \right) .$$

Then subs $s=\frac{1}{2}$, since $s-1=-\frac{1}{2}$, gives

$$ I =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}\Gamma  \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{4}  \right) . $$

You can do the same for the other one.

Comment: This is really great, but, as I said, this task is given just after definitions of FT and sine/cosine transforms, so, I suppose, no Mellin transforms are accepted.

Comment: First line: $\int f(x) {\bf dx}$ and +1 very nice twist...

Comment: @cdshines: You did not mention this in your post, but it is ok. It is a good technique to learn.

Comment: @draks...: thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I've edited my post to avoid further confusions, thank you.

Comment: So for the first one, are you saying that if omega = 1, that the integral is convergent? I am not doubting your work at all, but my first thought would be that because of the asymptote that for omega = 1 it would be divergent.

Comment: @imranfat: Check the convergence conditions for the Mellin transform for $\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$I_1(\omega)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot \cos (\omega\cdot x)\space dx,$$
and $$I_2(\omega)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\sin (\omega\cdot x)\space dx.$$
Let $x=t^2/\omega$ such that $dx=2t/\omega\space dt$, where $t\in [0,\infty)$. It follows that
$$I_1(\omega)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_0^\infty \cos (t^2)\space dt,$$
and
$$I_2(\omega)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_0^\infty \sin (t^2)\space dt.$$
Recognize that both integrands are even and exploit symmetry. It follows that
$$I_1(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos (t^2)\space dt,$$
and
$$I_2(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (t^2)\space dt.$$
Establish the equation
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\cos (t^2)-i\cdot\sin (t^2))\space dt.$$
Applying Euler's formula in complex analysis gives
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i\cdot t^2}dt.$$
Let $t=i^{-1/2}\cdot u$ such that $dt=i^{-1/2}\space du$, where $u\in(-\infty,\infty)$:
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=\frac{i^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{\omega}}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}du.$$
Evaluate the Gaussian integral:
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=i^{-1/2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}.$$
Make use of the general properties of the exponential function and logarithms in order to rewrite $i^{-1/2}$:
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=e^{\ln(i^{-1/2})}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}=e^{-1/2\cdot \ln(i)}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}.$$
In cartesian form, $i=0+i\cdot 1$. Therefore, in polar form, $i=1\cdot e^{i\cdot \pi/2}$. Taking the natural logarithm on both sides gives $\ln(i)=i\cdot\pi/2$. Substitution into the equation gives
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=e^{-i\cdot \pi/4}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}.$$
Applying Euler's formula in complex analysis gives
$$I_1(\omega)-i\cdot I_2(\omega)=(\cos(\pi/4)-i\cdot \sin(\pi/4))\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\cdot \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\omega}}.$$
Expanding the terms reveals that
$$I_1(\omega)=I_2(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\cdot\omega}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to give $\omega$ a small positive imaginary part $\omega\mapsto \omega+i\mu$ with $\mu>0$ (this essentially amounts to calculating the Laplace transform), and in the end send $\mu\to0$.
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(\mu-i\omega) x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu-i\omega}}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{y}}dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\mu-i\omega}}\,,
$$
where we recognized the Gaussian integral
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{y}}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}\,.
$$
Now, we use $(\mu-i\omega)^{-1/2}=\exp [-\frac{1}{2}\log(\mu-i\omega)]$ and recall that, choosing the branch line of the logarithm along the negative real axis,
$$
\lim_{\mu\to0}\log(\mu-i\omega)=\log|\omega|-i\frac{\pi}{2}\epsilon(\omega)
$$
where $\epsilon(\omega)$ denotes the sign of $\omega$, i.e. it is $+1$ if $\omega>0$ and $-1$ if $\omega<0$. 
Substituting above,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i\omega x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{|\omega|}}\exp\left[i\frac{\pi}{4}\epsilon(\omega)\right]
=\big[1+i\,\epsilon(\omega)\big]\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}}\,.
$$
Taking real and imaginary part,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}}\,,\qquad\quad
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\epsilon(\omega)\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2|\omega|}}\,.
$$